# TortoiseSVN: How to tag a subset of folders due to access rights?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have an SVN repository organized like:

```
project\trunk\folder1
project\trunk\folder2
project\trunk\folder3
```

I have read/write access to folder1 and folder2 but I do not have access to folder3.  When I use TortioseSVN to make a tag from the trunk I get an error, "Access to '/svn/project/!snv/rvr/123/trunk' forbidden".  Once I was given permission to access folder3 I was able to make the tag successfully.  Although, I didn't even know folder3 existed until I asked the administrator about the error.

Using TortoiseSVN, is there an easy way to make a tag containing a subset of folders or only the folders for which you have access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done currently.

Subversion doesn't allow copies (which is what making a tag does) when you do not have access to all children of what you are copying.  The reason for this is the access control system is based on paths and copying the file from one path to another path would subvert that access control.

For now your only decent option is to have someone who does have full access rights execute the copy command to create the tag.  You can't try and execute the copy command around the paths you don't have access to because you can't copy their parents either which would mean your ancestry would be wrong in the repo (which later might be important).

Comment: So what alternative would you suggest?  I suppose I would have to open the repo-browser, create a new folder under tags, and then copy each trunk subfolder individually to the new tags folder.  (It seems I can't select multiple folders and copy them all at once.)  Is there a better way?

Comment: added a paragraph to answer your comment.